# How to implement conditional COUNTIF in SQL?

Tags: sql

I am new to SQL and facing the problem for the while.
The question is how to create such Label column in SQL?

Goal: When group count is more than 1 it should be 'Y' otherwise 'N'

Here is what I do in Excel (please see screenshot).

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: I am using Exasol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want `case` with a window function:

```
select (case when count(*) over (partition by item) > 1 then 'Y' else 'N' end) as label
```

Comment: Thank you! It works on test env, now I am going to try it on real data and will return to you!